# Multicast sockets in Java

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, client-server

Hey Iam trying to write a chat server multicast program in Java, but it is not working as expected.

I have two files, ChatClient.java and ChatServer.java ( code below) .

The ChatClient sends a message to the server, which is then meant to recieve the message and print it out, but it does not recieve the message, can anyone notice why?

Client Code:

```
public class ChatClient {

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

 MulticastSocket chat = new MulticastSocket(8885);
 InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("224.2.2.5");
 chat.joinGroup(group);

 String msg = "";
 System.out.println("Type a message for the server:");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
 InputStreamReader(System.in));
 msg = br.readLine();
 DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(), 0, msg.length(), group, 8885);
 chat.send(data);
 chat.close();
 }
}
```

Server Code:

```
public class ChatServer {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

 MulticastSocket server = new MulticastSocket(8885);
 InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("224.2.2.5");
 //getByName - returns IP address of the given host
 server.joinGroup(group);

 boolean infinite = true;
 /* Server continually receives data and prints them */

 while(infinite) {

  byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
  DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
  server.receive(data);
  String msg = new String(data.getData()).trim();
  System.out.println(msg);
 }
 server.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Everything is working fine with your code..What are you expecting from this Code?

Comment: im expecting the server code to print the message that u enter when u run the client code, but it doesnt print anything. does this code work for you?? Thanks for the reply

Comment: Yes it is working fine for me..After client sends message to the server, Server prints it and exits..This is what the response of these codes.

Comment: really?? could it be a problem with how my operating system is set up?

Comment: Yeah it is.. how you executing your code? Some Exception is throwing while execution of your code?